# php and sql date-time help needed

Tags: php, sql

How would you convert the date-time coming from an SQL server into another format? The value coming from the SQL database is like `2013-09-23 12:20:30` and I want it to be displayed like `Sept-23 12:30 pm`.

I can send the date-time to server in this format by PHP, but then I will have a problem when I need to compare the date-time in SQL. The field in the database is set to the `datetime` type.

I've tried:

```
<?php
    if(substr($postainarray['time'],8,2) == $CurrDate) {
        $timetobeshown=substr($postainarray['time'],11,5);
    } else {
        $timetobeshown=substr($postainarray['time'],5,11);
    }
?>
<?=$timetobeshown?>
```

`$currDate` is today's date.

`$postinarray` is the array after the MySQL query.

After this code I get the desired format but not in desired style. If the date matches I get something like `14:00`, otherwise I get `09-24 18:09`, and I want it to be like `Sept-24 6:09 pm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a='2013-09-23 12:20:30';
echo date("M d g:i a",strtotime($a));
```

Answer (score 1):

for date format manipulation, the reference page is: [PHP:date Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

there you can checkout all the options you might need, and for your case it will be:

```
echo date("M-d g:i a", certaintaime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $date_from_db='2013-09-23 12:20:30';
    echo date("M-d g:i a",strtotime($date_from_db));
?>
```